# Unable to produce ROC curve in RCommander

Tags: r, roc

I have written the following code to plot ROC curve:

```
pred1 <- prediction(predict(modelID), LS_01RR$Payment_Ind)
perf1 <- performance(pred1,"tpr","fpr")
plot(perf1) 
plot(perf1,main="hivpr - ROC Curves",col="blue")
abline(0,1,col="grey")
```

But It doesn't plot. What is wrong here?

Answer (score -1):

Check your ROC object called ('perf1'). You probably did not create the object correctly.

Comment: Hello, the code worked previously, its that the plot isnt generated in my RCommander session